# JS, problema al validar email con símbolos

Tags: javascript, validación, email

recientemente hice una pregunta donde un campo email me estaba dando problemas al insertar símbolos delante del "@", encontré el validador, pero no tengo claro como hacer que me funcione, el validador es el siguiente:

```
items:[{
      fieldLabel: mail,
      id: 'mail1',
      name: 'mail',
      disabled: false,
      msgTarget: 'under',
      validator:function(v){
         if(!isNullUndefined(v)){
            var email = /^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;

      return email.test(v); 
     }
  } ........................................................................
```

Quiero que me acepte cosas como "micorreo-@mail.com", "miemail-@mail.com" y demás ¿Cómo podría hacerse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa otras cosas como las propiedades `fieldlabel`, `id`, etc. porque la expresión regular (lo que viene después de `var email = ...` es correcta y valida como quieres esos ejemplos que comentas.
Puedes hacer la prueba de que pasa la validación con el siguiente código añadiendo más elementos al array para comprobar numerosas opciones.

```
var correos = ["-em-@em.es","em||#@em.es","em\\\@em.es","em.es"],
    email = /^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;

correos.forEach(function(v) {
    console.log (v,": ",email.test(v)); 
})
```

También lo tienes en https://jsfiddle.net/tnrhgqs5/

El tema es que esa expresión regular (no sé de dónde la has sacado) vale para tu opción, pero ya habría que ver si cumple las reglas del standard de e-mails, por que por ejemplo la que puedes ver en https://regexr.com/2rhq7

Más información en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript